# Remove duplicate pairs from an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of pairs like the example below:

```
array = [["human KIR2DS1", 446.0], ["mouse BMP-4", 446.0], ["mouse BMP-4", 446.0], ["mTIMP2 lot DAAP01", "435a"], ["hKIR3DL3 lot DDBL01", "435a"]]
```

I want to remove the duplicate pairs in the array. What is the shortest method to do this?

Comment: How about using a `Set` instead so there's never a need to remove duplicates?

Comment: Set class is not present in 1.8.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
array.uniq
# => [["human KIR2DS1", 446.0], ["mouse BMP-4", 446.0], ["mTIMP2 lot DAAP01", "435a"], ["hKIR3DL3 lot DDBL01", "435a"]]
```

or if you want to modify the original array:

```
array.uniq!
array # => [["human KIR2DS1", 446.0], ["mouse BMP-4", 446.0], ["mTIMP2 lot DAAP01", "435a"], ["hKIR3DL3 lot DDBL01", "435a"]]
```

Comment: It compares the elements using `#hash` and `#eql?` methods, so you can use it for the basic data types and structures (int, hashes, arrays, floats, strings). If you use custom objects though, you have to define these two methods in order for the `uniq` to work. Refer to https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/129677

Answer (score 0):

also this can be used to sort out the duplicate and return a new Set of array wihtout duplicate. I use the spread operator "..."

```
function unique(array) {
    return [...new Set(array)];
}
```